# SQL dateformat while creating table

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

im trying to make an SQL table with custom date format

```
CREATE TABLE Basketbal.Bestuurslid (
`lidnummer` INT NOT NULL,
`begin_datum` DATE NOT NULL,
`eind_datum` DATE NULL,
`functie` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`lidnummer`, `begin_datum`));
(I know it's in dutch)
```

im trying to make `begin_datum` & `eind_datum` in the following format:
`1-jan-07 ('%e-%b-%y')`

but I cant get it to work

any suggestions?

Comment: Normally you'd let the database worry about the format it's stored in, and instead convert it to the format you'd like after you have selected the data (This can also be done within the select itself: https://davidwalsh.name/format-date-mysql-date_format)

Comment: I am waiting for you in the future with another question about how to convert `1-jan-07` to date type. You should store dates as dates in database. Formatting can be applied on client app.

Comment: The conversions look like MySQL so I added the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date` is an internal format in the database.  You can convert it to (or from) a string using `date_format()` (and `str_to_date()`).  That controls the *character* representation of the value, not the value itself.  So, when you select from the table:

```
select date_format(begin_datum, '%e-%b-%y')
```

If you really feel strongly about not explicitly calling this function, you can put the date logic into a view and access the table through the view.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your data stored in your table you could pull your data in the format you want it, example:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),begin_datum,6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your awnsers. i solved it by not using the format DATE and just using VARCHAR();

kind regards,

Chiel

Comment: Slow claps. So, you've decided to do away with making use of data types at all? After all, you're storing dates as strings - why not numbers as well? We normally use data types so that we're protected from errors. What's now going to stop someone storing `29-feb-15` in this column? (And note that, strangely, nobody ever asks how to store *numbers* in a database in strange ways - they accept that numbers are just numbers and any formatting you want to do with them can be done easily later - and yet people perpetually ask how to store *dates* with associated formatting. Strange)

Comment: I did not think about that, but your totaly right. I will store them as a normal date and like @Gordon Linoff said, use the "select date_format" while reading the database. I tested this and it seems to work.

thank you for the error detaction :)